# When filing part time residency how does one determine interest earned in which state?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I am filing in two states. My residency ends up being about 60-40. On the state forms it asks Interest and Dividend from State sources. Do I have to claim it on both, or do I just claim it on the state that I am now a legal resident of as of 12/31/10?

I did not know if I had to check dates and split it up or claim it in both. Any help on where I can find this answer would be amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

States handle part-year residents differently.  The answer will depend on which states you lived in last year.